# OpenEHR and blood pressure

Tags: openehr

I'm new to openEHR. How do I go about recording whether a blood pressure is considered to be 'high' or 'low.' There isn't any information about this in the blood pressure archetype.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Yampeyu an openEHR archetype gives you the basis information structure in a standardized way, that allows you to put a knowlege layer on top of that in the form of rules.

At an implementation level you need:

1. the rule that says what is clinically "high" or "low" or "right" or "wrong", which might contain different variables that should be populated from a clinical data repository (CDR) for evaluating the rule.
2. data queries to get data associated to your rule, to be able to populate your rule variables.
3. you need data, compliant with and archetype and template in a CDR.
4. the archetypes and templates.

Those are the layers in reverse order, everything starts with 4., then it is 3, 2, 1 and then you can integrate and use your rules in your systems, for instance, to provider clinical decision support, or do analytics, generate reports, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Blood pressure archetype in CKM doesn't currently contain this kind of knowledge, mostly because the more values you consider (e.g. age, sex, pregnancy status) the ranges differ.

This doesn't mean that you can't say that in a template: Archetypes allow you to define additional rules to provide the knowledge to the validation or generation systems.
A part of that rule would look something like this (completely invented example):

> normal_range_young_male : $ageYears>14 and $ageYears<19 and
>   $systolicBP>105 and $systolicBP<120 implies $bpconsideration=[at9999]

Where [at9999] would be defined as "Normal Blood Pressure" and could even be linked to the corresponding snomed-ct term